# tacacs+ for Linux authentication/authorization using pam_tacplus

Tags: linux, security, authentication, authorization, pam

I am using TACACS+ to authenticate Linux users using pam_tacplus.so PAM module and it works without issues.

I have modified the pam_tacplus module to meet some of my custom requirements.

I know by default, TACACS+ does not have any means to support linux groups or access level control over linux bash commands, however, I was wondering is there any way that some information could be passed from TACACS+ server side to let the pam_tacplus.so module which can be used to allow/deny , or modify the user group on the fly [from pam module itself].

Example: If I could pass the priv-lvl number from server to the client and which could be used for some decision making at the PAM module.

PS: I would prefer a method which involved no modification at the server side [code], all modification should be done at Linux side ie pam_tacplus module.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually I got it working.

Issue 1:

The issue I faced was there is very few documentation available to configure TACACS+ server for a non CISCO device.

Issue 2:

The tac_plus version that I am using

```
tac_plus -v
tac_plus version F4.0.4.28
```

does not seem to support

```
service = shell protocol = ssh
```

option in tac_plus.conf file.

So eventually I used

```
service = system  {
                default attribute = permit
                priv-lvl = 15
        }
```

On the client side (pam_tacplus.so),

I sent the AVP service=system at authorization phase(pam_acct_mgmt), which forced the service to return priv-lvl defined at the configuration file, which I used to device privilege level of the user.

NOTE: In some documentations it is mentioned that service=system is not used anymore. So this option may not work with CISCO devices.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you intend to implement this, PAM may be insufficient to meet your needs. The privilege level from TACACS+ isn't part of the 'authentication' step, but rather the 'authorization' step. If you're using pam_tacplus, then that authorization takes place as part of the 'account' (aka pam_acct_mgmt) step in PAM. Unfortunately, however, *nix systems don't give you a lot of ability to do fine grained control here -- you might be able to reject access based on invalid 'service', 'protocol', or even particulars such as 'host', or 'tty', but probably not much beyond that. (priv_lvl is part of the request, not response, and pam_tacplus *always* sends '0'.)

If you want to vary privileges on a *nix system, you probably want to work within that environments capabilities. My suggestion would be to grouping as a means of producing a sort of 'role-based' access controls. If you want these to exist on the TACACS+ server, then you'll want to introduce custom AVP that are meaningful, and then associate those with the user.

You'll likely need an NSS (name service switch) module to accomplish this -- by the time you get to PAM, OpenSSH, for example, will have already determined that your user is "bogus" and send along a similarly bogus password to the server. With an NSS module you can populate 'passwd' records for your users based on AVPs from the TACACS+ server. More details on NSS can be found in glibc's documentation for "[Name Service Switch](https://goo.gl/lvwVHn)".

Comment: thanks for the help. I believe a good long term solution is to have NSS module to this, but as of now I got it working with a workaround.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've got a working NSS module that I'm trying to get open sourced by my company. It is in the works, but I don't have a clear time frame. Cheers.